# Appointment App - AngularJS availability selection

Tags: java, mysql, angularjs

I developed an application using Java Spring (backend api), mysql (DB) and Anguljar JS (frontend) that is designed to let users schedule an appointment. The endtime of each appointment is five minutes after its starttime, between 8 o’clock and 2 p.m.

In my data base I have the following information:
 •  A table named “turno” which contains the parameters time and date of the appointments given.
 •  Another table contains all the available appointments.

I want to substract both arrays so as to see which appointments have not been given yet. The objective is not to allow users to fix an appointment that has already been made by someone else.

Does anyone have any idea how to do this?

Data examples:

[image: DB example MAIN Table]

Java Example:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "turno")
public class Turno implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private Long id;
private String solicitante;
private String telefono;
private TipoDocumento tipoDocumento;
private String numeroDocumento;
private String email;
private Horario horario;
private String numeroTurno;
private String fecha;
private Date formatfecha;
private Date controlFecha;


@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "id")
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Column(name = "solicitante")
public String getSolicitante() {
    return solicitante;
}

public void setSolicitante(String solicitante) {
    this.solicitante = solicitante;
}

@Column(name = "telefono")
public String getTelefono() {
    return telefono;
}

public void setTelefono(String telefono) {
    this.telefono = telefono;
}

@Column(name = "numero_documento")
public String getNumeroDocumento() {
    return numeroDocumento;
}

public void setNumeroDocumento(String numeroDocumento) {
    this.numeroDocumento = numeroDocumento;
}

@Column(name = "email")
public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
@JoinColumn(name = "horario", referencedColumnName = "id")
public Horario getHorario() {
    return horario;
}

public void setHorario(Horario horario) {
    this.horario = horario;
}

@Column(name = "numero_turno")
public String getNumeroTurno() {
    return numeroTurno;
}

public void setNumeroTurno(String numeroTurno) {
    this.numeroTurno = numeroTurno;
}

@Column(name = "fecha")
public String getFecha() {
    return fecha;
}

public void setFecha(String fecha) {
    this.fecha = fecha;
}

@Column(insertable = false, updatable = false, name = "fecha")
public Date getFormatFecha() {
    return formatfecha;
}

public void setFormatFecha(Date formatfecha) {
    this.formatfecha = formatfecha;
}

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
@JoinColumn(name = "tipoDocumento", referencedColumnName = "id")
public TipoDocumento getTipoDocumento() {
    return tipoDocumento;
}

public void setTipoDocumento(TipoDocumento tipoDocumento) {
    this.tipoDocumento = tipoDocumento;
}

@Column(name = "fecha_control")
public Date getControlFecha() {
    return controlFecha;
}

public void setControlFecha(Date controlFecha) {
    this.controlFecha = controlFecha;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((numeroTurno == null) ? 0 : numeroTurno.hashCode());
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Turno other = (Turno) obj;
    if (numeroTurno == null) {
        if (other.numeroTurno != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!numeroTurno.equals(other.numeroTurno))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

}

Updated

Comment: You want to select all the valid hours and delete those that were already taken by other people?

Comment: Examples of the data structure (false data of course) would help to come up with potential options for solving your problem.  Also, are you looking to solve this client side or server side when you load the available options?

Comment: You will need to query the database constantly to check if an hour has been taken (or check every time the user chooses an hour) and update the selections. Take this into account if You expect a lot of users simultaneously.

Comment: Yes I would like to show the avaible hours only, I´m willing to try and fix this both server or client side. I´m not expecting a lot of user simultaneously. Post updates with data examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heres how I fixed it in case anyone is interested:

Method in the controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/horario/{fecha}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public Object queryHorariosLibres(@PathVariable("fecha") Date fecha) {

    List<Long> horariosLibres = null;
    List<Long> turnosTomados = turnoService.getTurnosTomados(fecha);

    Calendar dia = new GregorianCalendar();
    dia.setTime(fecha);

    Horario horario = horarioRepository.findByDia(dia.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));  

    horariosLibres = horario.getHorariosLibres(turnosTomados);

    if (horariosLibres == null) {
    return "hola";
    } 
    else
    return horariosLibres;
}
```

Local methods:

```
@Transient
public List<Long> getHorarios(){
    List<Long> horarios = new ArrayList<Long>();

    for(Long i = horarioInicio; i <= horarioFin; i+=300){
        horarios.add(i);
    }
    return horarios;

}

@Transient
public List<Long> getHorariosLibres(List<Long> horariosTomados){

    List<Long> horariosLibres = getHorarios();
    horariosLibres.removeAll(horariosTomados);

    return horariosLibres;

}
```